# Transparent TextBlock with DockPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a splash screen where an image and load status (textblock with progress bar) are located one on top of another one.

I've wrote next code:

```
<Window 
        WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent"/>
        <ProgressBar Maximum="100" Value="{Binding ProgressValue, Mode=OneWay}" Height="5" Grid.Row="1" IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsIndeterminate}"/>
    </Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="None"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Unfortunately TextBlock still removes some part of the picture it is located on top of. I think the reason is DockPanel, but I'm not sure how to do it other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextBlock` does not remove part of the `Image` as it's not on top of it but below it. It's because `DockPanel` does not put children on top of each other. If you want to put inner `Grid` on top of `Image` then easiest solution is to replace `DockPanel` with `Grid`

```xml
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="None" />
    <Grid Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>            
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <ProgressBar Maximum="100" Value="{Binding ProgressValue, Mode=OneWay}" Height="5" Grid.Row="1" IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsIndeterminate}"/>            
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```